# how to clear cache in SharePoint

Tags: cache, distributedcache

How do I clear cache for a AD distribution group? I recently had a change in outgoing smtp via central admin. I have a workflow that sends email to a distribution group which has been working great. all after the smtp change distribution group is being routed to another distribution group by SharePoint. Is there a way to clear cache so that it doesn't do that. Messaging team emailed me the log showing how sharepoint re-routing to a another distribution group.

Answer (score 0):

Go to User profile service app and run the User Profile Sync job

Comment: Distribution groups are not different than user profile.

Comment: User profile sync causes the reanalysed of ad groups checking the membership of those groups.

Comment: I dont mind doing that but I have hand selected certain OU and certain users. Dont I have go through and do this again?

Comment: No you just run the incremental sync job. If you look at the process at the end after users profiles have been updated then there is a bit which enumerates AD groups, updating membership info.Really your farm should be running this everyday so you capture changes to people's AD records.

Comment: The incremental runs every 4 hours. but I will go ahead and run it manually.